# csv utf-8 writer - compability with python2.4

Tags: python, utf-8, csv

At the bottom of this manual http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html we have example of UnicodeWriter

But how can i use this example in python 2.4

I got exception about codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)(). 
Property getincrementalencoder created only in version 2.5. Who can replace this property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will work, but try to use `codecs.getencoder` instead.